# KVM TFTP Boot / WDS

Tags: kvm-virtualization, pxe-boot, wds

I installed all my Chef Infrastructure, PXE install of my Linux VM's, Preseed/Kickstart, etc. via KVM on my local server (Host OS is Debian 8). Installing a new Linux VM is a piece of cake with that setup.

Now i want to start with Windows Systems (configure with Chef, build up testlabs, etc.).
But to install them, i need to create an WDS/WSUS Server - and thats my problem, how can i boot from them?

Is there a way in the pxe boot menu to give the client the WDS URL?
So the Linux Server is still booting normal and when i choose my "Windows Install" option, it boots the WDS PXE.

Example menu entry i found, but not tested now:

```
LABEL WDS
PXE tftp://WDS-Server/pxe/pxelinux.0
```

I think its pxechain i have to use right? Still reading how WDS works and how i can install Win7 and above clients over network, so i still have time ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to PXE boot into your WDS server you must PXE boot i.e. WDS' LiteTouch.wim file. After booting one of those files (32 or 64) you will get access to the WDS repository menu.

In order to PXE boot a bootable wim you must load i.e. pxeboot.n12 as NBP, next it'll ask for the files bootmgr.exe, BCD, boot.sdi, and finaly for the WDS WIM file i.e. LiteTouch32.wim.

Comment: Thanks, i wrote it down, wasn´t that easy to test, but it works. When i´am done, i post it here.